# Make one normal mode command while in insert mode in zsh's vi mode

Tags: zsh, vi-mode, zle

Zsh vi mode doesn't have ctrl-o behavior set by default how do I get to work like in vim ?

Comment: Zsh has a _vi_ mode, not a _vim_ mode. This is a vim-specific feature so it's unsurprising that zsh doesn't have it. It's probably doable with a custom widget though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's as simple as this:

```bash
vi-cmd () {
  local REPLY

  # Read the next keystroke, look it up in the `vicmd` keymap and, if successful,
  # evalute the widget bound to it in the context of the `vicmd` keymap.
  zle .read-command -K vicmd && 
      zle $REPLY -K vicmd
}

# Make a keyboard widget that calls the function above.
zle -N vi-cmd

# Bind the widget to Ctrl-O in the `viins` keymap.
bindkey -v '^O' vi-cmd
```

Comment: It works but still wouldn't do some key shortcuts like "d" to delete

Comment: @Hazemgamal I updated my answer with a fix. Please try again.